# Is there any way I can put a trigger to toggle Bootstrap modal inside a controller function in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I want to create a module where a student must provide his/her student ID, pin, and email to validate his/her account. If the user entered correct id, pin and email, a modal that will set his/her password must appear.

**View**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('mycontroller/validateStud');?>" name="formvalidate">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="idnum" placeholder="ID Number"/>
    <br>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="mail" placeholder="Student Email"/>
    <br>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pin" placeholder="Student PIN"/>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%;" onclick="" name="submit2" value="<?php echo $this->uri->uri_string(); ?>" id="validated">Validate</button>
  </div>
 </form>

 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
   </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller** mycontroller.php

```
public function validateStud()
{
  $submit=$this->input->post('submit2');
  $studentId=$this->input->post('idnum');
  $saispin=$this->input->post('pin');
  $mail=$this->input->post('mail');

  $res=$this->mymodel->checkValidation($studentId, $pin, $mail);
  if (isset($_POST['submit2']) && $res) { //if the three inputs matched with a student record
   //Open MyModal that will set account password
  }
  else if(isset($_POST['submit2']) && !$res)
  {
    //No record found
  }
  else
  {
    redirect('index', true);
  }
}
```

I've tried javascript, but I failed. Enlighten me please. Any help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to post the values to the server using ajax, so that you can trigger the modal opening in the success callback. That way if it failed, you could also trigger it to open with a different message. It would be cleaner.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: '',
    data: {},
    success: function(){},
    error: function(){}
});
```

Something like this. Check the jQuery docs for more info